# STM32H755ZIT6 STLINK Debug

Tags: stm32, debugging, swd, st-link, nucleo

I've just got new [NUCLEO STM32H755ZIT6 board](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-h755zi-q.html#overview) with STLinkV3 on it.
I just want to debug simple empty STMCube project and after configuring board According it's

Please look in the [UM2408 User manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um2408-stm32h7-nucleo144-boards-mb1363-stmicroelectronics.pdf) (images below).

I got "NO STLink detected" and LD5 is Green and LD3 blinking RED (you can see them on board image)

Also STLinkUpgrade does not see onboard STLINKV3 at all

As the USER MANUAL says you can power the board using STLINK's USB connector[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try change USB cable. Are you sure that your USB cable has data lines? Do not use cables from earphone charger or something like this.

Comment: I tested mine nucleo and it behaves exactly as you describe when connected using cable without data wires.

Comment: @Misaz And how did you fix this problem?

Comment: Changed USB cable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use USB cable which has no data lines or cable is broken or USB port in the computer is broken. Flashing red indicates no USB enumeration between ST-Link and PC happended. Try different USB cable. Do not use cables which you received with charger for some cheap device like earphones. These cables are usualy chepest one and manufacturer includes only power wires and no data wires (for saving material and money, of course).

Comment: I'll try, but any other ideas?

Comment: other ideas are not needed until you try new/different USB cable. If fails you can try different USB port on the PC. If fails, you can try different PC. If fails, you can try different nucleo board.

Comment: Changed USB cable, it works.. thanks